# Paginar el resultado de una consulta con Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Estoy trabajando con la versión 6 de Entity Framework junto con SQL Server localdb 13.0.2151.

Tengo 4 entidades Profesores, Recursos, Materias y Asignaciones.
[image: Modelo de Entidades]

La consulta que intento hacer debe recuperar todas las Asignaciones junto con sus Recursos y Materias para un Profesor dado.

```
var asignacionesPaginadas = await db.Asignaciones.AsNoTracking()
.Where(a => a.Profesores.ProfesorId==profesorId)
.Include(a => a.Materia)
.Include(a => a.Recurso)
.OrderBy(a => a.FechaHoraReserva)
.Skip(_paginado.CantidadPorPagina * _paginado.PaginaActual)
.Take(_paginado.CantidadPorPagina)
.ToListAsync();
```

Y no obtengo los resultados esperados. Usando el Profiler veo que genera:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[AsignacionId] AS [AsignacionId], 
[Project1].[FechaHoraReserva] AS [FechaHoraReserva], 
[Project1].[MateriaId] AS [MateriaId], 
[Project1].[Nombre] AS [Nombre], 
[Project1].[Carrera] AS [Carrera], 
[Project1].[RecursoId] AS [RecursoId], 
[Project1].[Descripcion] AS [Descripcion]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[AsignacionId] AS [AsignacionId], 
    [Extent1].[FechaHoraReserva] AS [FechaHoraReserva], 
    [Extent2].[MateriaId] AS [MateriaId], 
    [Extent2].[Nombre] AS [Nombre], 
    [Extent2].[Carrera] AS [Carrera], 
    [Extent3].[RecursoId] AS [RecursoId], 
    [Extent3].[Descripcion] AS [Descripcion]
    FROM   [dbo].[Asignaciones] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Materias] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Materia_MateriaId] = [Extent2].[MateriaId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Recursos] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Recurso_RecursoId] = [Extent3].[RecursoId]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Profesor_ProfesorId] = @p0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[FechaHoraReserva] ASC
OFFSET @p1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @p2 ROWS ONLY
```

Investigando un poco pienso que tiene que ver la interfase    `IOrderedQueryable` pero no logro entenderla.

En fin, ¿es posible con Linq generar la siguiente consulta?:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AsignacionId] AS [AsignacionId], 
[Extent1].[FechaHoraReserva] AS [FechaHoraReserva], 
[Extent2].[MateriaId] AS [MateriaId], 
[Extent2].[Nombre] AS [Nombre], 
[Extent2].[Carrera] AS [Carrera], 
[Extent3].[RecursoId] AS [RecursoId], 
[Extent3].[Descripcion] AS [Descripcion]
FROM   [dbo].[Asignaciones] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Materias] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Materia_MateriaId] = [Extent2].[MateriaId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Recursos] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Recurso_RecursoId] = [Extent3].[RecursoId]
WHERE [Extent1].[Profesor_ProfesorId] = @p0
ORDER BY [Extent1].[FechaHoraReserva] ASC
OFFSET @p1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @p2 ROWS ONLY
```

Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. Ambas consultas parecen equivalentes. ¿Hay alguna diferencia que no veo? ¿O es simplemente que no te gusta la forma como el SQL se ve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este comportamiento de generar una consulta de la consulta principal lo genera el método `.OrderBy()` y no es que esté mal, así es el funcionamiento de LinQ. La respuesta es porque **Entity Framework** divide la expresión de la consulta en un árbol de expresiones y luego utiliza ese árbol de expresiones para generar la consulta, he ahí el motivo.

## Actualización

No podría poner un código del cómo podría quedar tu código dado que como comenta `sstan` primero se deben ordenar los resultados y luego invocar `Skip()` y `Take()` para devolver la página seleccionada.

Comment: No, la alternativa que presentas cambiaría completamente los resultados. Para devolver una "página" de resultados correctamente, hay que ordenar los resultados *antes* de usar el `Skip` y `Take`.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, editaré mi respuesta